# For a read only user why do DROP and INSERT fail with different errors

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database user with read only permissions for table example_table.

```
Select * from example_table;
```

Works fine.

```
insert into example_table values('example');
```

Fails as expected. "insufficient privileges"

```
drop table example_table;
```

Fails with error message "table or view does not exist"

My question is. Why do the last two examples not both fail with "insufficient privileges" why when used in the ddl statement can it not even see the table?

Oracle 10g

Thank you.

Comment: For me in 11g it shows always `insufficient privileges`. Seems like a bug of Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `SELECT` would fail without a synonym, so you're not selecting directly from the table, but through a synonym.

`DROP TABLE` is [DDL](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language&ei=wP4VU-HkJ5PG7AaIooDgCw&usg=AFQjCNGW01lbpJ_pOsZm3_mSQ-QTxfWNvA&sig2=oEgj0wrasigx15W6sA7a3A&bvm=bv.62286460,d.ZGU), and [synonyms can't be used in most DDL statements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm). So in your case the statement goes after a real object (by default in the current schema if you have not specified an owner), doesn't find any object by that name, hence the (admittedly unhelpful) error message.

If instead you had written:

```
drop table owner.example_table;
```

Then you would have received the expected error message.